# Tcp connection in lan directly between two devices

Tags: routes, tcp, tcpclient

I have machines that have 2 pcs inside. One is a tcp server and one is a client. There is also a switch inside the cabinet. Both pcs are connected to the switch. This seitch is then connected to the central router. So basically the switch has both pcs and the router connected. All devices have a fixed IP configured.

Now, if the client sends a packet to the server, what path will it take? Will it go to the switch, router, switch, server, or just switch, server?

I tried connecting the two pcs directly and it works, so i am not sure that the router is involved.

If the router is involved, is there a way to force a direct connection?